# Cocoa - Bindings - Tableview - How to calculate sum of columns

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

Let's say I have an Entity named **Values** and it has three attributes: **A, B and SUM**.

I have a tableview where **Column A** and **Column B** is bound to the attributes **A** and **B**. The user can change the values of the first to columns (**A,B**) but not the third (**SUM**).

Now to my question:
The user should not be able to edit the third column (**SUM**). That column should only show the sum of **A * B**. How can I accomplish that? Can I use bindings in IB for that as well?

Many thanks.

[image: SUM = A*B]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a variable to my entity subclass:

```
- (NSUInteger) sumOf1And2 {
    NSUInteger value1 = [self.a intValue];
    NSUInteger value2 = [self.b intValue];

    return value1 + value2;
}
```